# Client machine not able to connect with xmlrpc server, hosted on EC2 cloud Server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cloud, simplexmlrpcserver

I have ubuntu instance on Ec2 cloud server and on same instance I have created xmlrpc server using simpleXMLRP. I'd like to access server methods from my local ubuntu machine.but when I tried to do so, it raised "**Protocol Error**" as below,

> "XMLRPC Error :  xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: ProtocolError for ec2-70-41-59-2.amazonaws.com:8000/Common: -1 >"

As per the link http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html. protocol error will occur, if the server named by the URI does not exist. but server is running on the cloud.

What is this error and how do I fix it ? does any changes required on Amazon cloud, for giving access to particular host and port? if so, what changes should be apply?

Comment: not yet, but I have set rule (in Security Group of Ec2 cloud server) for "All TCP" with access to 8000 port and it starts working :)

Comment: @Yajushi As you have figured out the answer to this question yourself,  could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may help someone to solve the same problem,

1) Select your (or default) Security Group in Ec2 Section of cloud Server.

2) Select "Inbound" Tab and create new Rule for "All TCP" and give access to your required port.

as per my knowledge, second step will inform cloud server to open selected port for Inbound access from end users.